# Does OpenCL have any concept of a bitmap?

Tags: opencl

I am learning about memory buffers and images in OpenCL. From what I understand an image in OpenCL is just an abstract data structure and doesn't have anything to do with a photograph-like image (x,y,r,g,b or x,y,h,s,l,a, or... whatever).

In this book I am reading they provide a [function](http://codepad.org/0uldc8Un) to read a .bmp file off the HDD and convert it into a float array

Then they write the float array to a cl_mem variable:

```
// GET THE .BMP AS A FLOAT[]
float* inputImage = readImage(inputFile, &imageWidth, &imageHeight);

// DEFINE THE IMAGE AND FORMAT 
cl_image_desc desc;
desc.image_type = CL_MEM_OBJECT_IMAGE2D;
desc.image_width = imageWidth;
desc.image_height = imageHeight;
desc.image_depth = 0;
desc.image_array_size = 0;
desc.image_row_pitch = 0;
desc.image_slice_pitch = 0;
desc.num_mip_levels = 0;
desc.num_samples = 0;
desc.buffer = NULL;
cl_image_format format;
format.image_channel_order = CL_R;     
format.image_channel_data_type = CL_FLOAT; 

// DEFINE AND WRITE THE IMAGE
cl_mem d_inputImage = clCreateImage(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, &format, &desc, NULL, NULL);
ize_t origin[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };  
size_t region[3] = { imageWidth, imageHeight, 1 }; 
clEnqueueWriteImage(queue, d_inputImage, CL_FALSE, origin, region, 0, 0, inputImage, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

So does any of that tell OpenCL that we are dealing with a photo-like image or are we just defining a data structure? In the kernel of this book they use:

```
// sourceImage is d_inputImage from the previous block of code. its type is image2d_t
float4 pixel;
pixel = read_imagef(sourceImage, sampler, coords);
sum.x += pixel.x * filter[filterIdx++];
```

Does OpenCL just loosely use these data structures as photo-like images or is it in any way similiar to .NET where you can create a Bitmap object from many different sources and then once you have that object you can do whatever you want with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no:

> Does OpenCL have any concept of a bitmap?

No, as an actual Bitmap (c)(R)(tm) image file format, but it has the general abstract/concept of bitmap (images) in memory. The latter is not the same as the former! The file format is a simple RIFF resource container, while the latter is a general concept.

> is it in any way similar to .NET where you can create a Bitmap object from many different sources

No. You cannot simply read or write various file formats.

> Does OpenCL just loosely use these data structures as photo-like images

Yes (kinda, a little more).

`OpenCL` does know about RAW image formats in memory, but the support doesn't cover PNG, JPG or other actual file formats. `OpenCL` doesn't have that whole coverage of image file format support as the `.NET Class Library`. (But that's correct, since it's not `OpenCL`'s goal or role at all. `OpenCL` and `.NET` are not comparable in this respect, they are totally different animals.)

.NET can read and write many different file formats. `OpenCL` can handle various **RAW formats** (different RGB orders and bit depth) once they are **in memory**. But it's your task to find the way how to read/write that RAW data from/into an actual file: OpenCL doesn't support JPG, PNG, GIF or other compression and file formats out of the box. For example, if you want to read/write `JPEG`, then you can use [libjpeg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg/), similarly [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) in case of `PNG`, and so on. These libraries are all open source and that's how the whole ecosystem comes together.

And that's probably also the reason why the book provided a simple routine to read and write a very small subset of `BMP` raw format. (Bitmap can have several color depth, `RLE` compression etc). So keep in mind that the book routine can handle only one specific "sub-format" of `BMP`. I'd advise `PNG` in a real world scenario, since RAW data can take up amazingly huge space, which decreases performance (of course there's a trade-off for the compression runtime itself).
One more thing about the book's routine: it is tailored to the `OpenCL` kernel needs, and it provides float array, and it's only one channel (`format.image_channel_order = CL_R;`). You usually receive integer `RGB` color channel components from image libraries. But converting it to float is no biggie (unless you have a ton of data).

Comment: thanks to both of you for your help (sorry i can only mark one as answer). one last thing. is this statement correct? the inputImage (in this case a grayscale image turned into an array of floats so 1 float per pixel) might look something like {255, 255, 250, 248, 250...etc}. i write it to a cl_mem with clEnqueueWriteImage using a CL_R format. then i read pixels on the kernel with read_imagef which returns a float4 (4 element vector). because this is a single channel image the value for the pixel is stored is stored in the x coordinate (of the float4 returned by read_imagef).

Comment: @user1873073 You are correct. See http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/read_imagef2d.html `(r, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` float4 in case of `CL_R`.

Answer (score 2):

> Does OpenCL have any concept of a bitmap?

Certainly; the `cl_image_desc` type (together with its `cl_image_format`) represents an image (or bitmap).  If you compare the properties or fields set in your code example with the properties of the `Bitmap` class, you will find they are almost the same, perhaps with slight naming differences:

- [Bitmap Properties (.NET System.Drawing)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap_properties.aspx)

The real difference is that OpenCL is only concerned with images in memory, and processing those images quickly and efficiently.  OpenCL does not concern itself with I/O, file formats, codecs and so on.

> So does any of that tell OpenCL that we are dealing with a photo-like image or are we just defining a data structure?

Yes. The `cl_image_desc` completely describes how to interpret the image data in memory. This corresponds to the way in which your processing kernels work on this data (eg. greyscale or single channel image, RGBA and so on).  You can think of a photo-like image as a blob of binary data in memory that has all this extra metadata to make sense of it as a photo-like image.  So it is in a sense a superset of a simple buffer (or `cl_buffer`).

> Does OpenCL just loosely use these data structures as photo-like images or is it in any way similiar to .NET where you can create a Bitmap object from many different sources and then once you have that object you can do whatever you want with it?

The scope of OpenCL is to provide a framework for high-performance heterogeneous (ie. CPU and GPU) processing of data in a cross-platform API.  It is not trying to be an entire platform like .NET, which also provides file I/O, graphics rendering, and so forth.  The idea with OpenCL is that it fits in with whatever platform code you are already using.  You use your platform code (.NET, Cocoa, libjpeg or whatever) to load the file into memory, decoding from whatever on-disk representation and codec you happen to use.  Then you can pass this data to OpenCL, describing it by means of these structures, to be processed.

So effectively you can create OpenCL images from any of these same sources, once they are in memory. After you have finished running your processing kernels, you can then take the data out of the OpenCL structures and pass the results to the rest of your code and use the platform APIs to render the results to screen or save them back as encoded files.